# Is it possible to include plot lines on cpselect image?

Tags: image, matlab

Is it possible to display detected lines in an image and then use that image, keeping the lines, as one of the two images in the MATLAB cpselect tool?

If I detect the lines in an image like below:

[image]

How can I then display this image along with the plotted lines in the cpselect tool ??

Is the only solution to save a new image with these lines in the image and then use the new combined image in the cpselect tool or is there a way to plot the lines along with the image in the cpselect tool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the code behind the cpselect tool I have found that the image input arguments for cpselect will only accept numeric or logical types.  To me that means the only way lines could be displayed on the images that are input into cpselect, is if the lines are actually part of the images.

This could be done by finding all of the points that make up the line, either by using the line's equation or by using an algorithm such as [Bresenham's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to find the points between two endpoints.  Once the points are acquired, alter the images pixel intensity values at the location of the line points.  After this is done the new image can then be read into the cpselect tool.

For my project I decided to drop my usage of the cpselect tool.  I just created a figure containing my image, used plot to display my lines on the image, and then used the getpts function to allow the user to select points from the image.

```
I = imread('image1.png');
lines = ARRAY OF LINE ENDPOINTS IN COLUMNS OF 'y1 x1 y2 x2'

ref = figure();
imshow(I)
hold on
for k = 1:length(lines)
    xy = [lines(k,2),lines(k,4); lines(k,1), lines(k,3)]
    plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
end

[rx, ry] = getpts(ref);
```

Although I don't feel the end result is as intuitive for the user compared to using cpselect, it did do what I wanted.